# why {action} is not present in default routing template (ASP.NET Web API)

Tags: asp.net-web-api

why {action} is not in included in the default routing template for ASP.NET Web API projects?

The below code is generated by default:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",                    
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 1):

Web Api is design to be a [restful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) Api and when creating a restful Api one of the most important things is to have a correct relationship between the URL and the HTTP methods.
For each entity (controller) there should be a GET, POST, PUT and DELETE method which all are operating on the entity level.

If we create a controller named UserController, this should then expose the entity User on the http level. 
To fullfill the restful principle the controller should be able to handle most of these request

```
GET api/user
GET api/user/id
POST api/user
PUT api/user
PUT api/user/id
DELETE api/user
DELETE api/user/id
```

By default, Web API is designed to support these restful requests and that's most likely why the default route is set to only be `"api/{controller}/{id}"` as that is the minimum requirement to support a restful implementation of an api

Comment: Your reply seems very reasonable and logical and although I have up-voted it but I can't straight forward accept it as "The answer" until I find some reasoning FROM Microsoft team.

Answer (score 0):

as indicated in official doc, In Web API, the usual convention is to omit "{action}".
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection

Comment: That is what I already know. I am searching for the WHY part.